# How to Track Table Usage

Tags: sql-server-2017, table, logging

I need to track usage for 1 table, and log how this table is accessed (select, insert, etc.) and by which logins

What is the proper way to do it using `SQL Server Audit` and `Extended Events` ?
If there any other ways to track usage, please share it, too

Thanks!

Comment: What information do you require? Is it simply counts of access broken down by login and action (select, insert, update) or do you need specifics about what queries were executed? Maybe expand on why you need the information to help identify the best solution.

Comment: @HandyD yes also need specifics about queries being executed, but also if you can show counts of access broken down by login and action, would be good too